# How do you execute payloads with javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to execute payloads with javascript in the browser

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48624660/how-to-execute-a-code-encoded-in-base64-in-javascript) you can execute base64 code

`index.html`

```
<html>
<script>
var encoded = "base64 payload goes here";
var decodedString = atob(encoded);
eval(decodedString);
</script> 
</html>
```

When you check the console in developer tools you get the following error
`Uncaught SyntaxError: illegal character`

To generate the payload I used metasploit.
I tried using the format `js_le` with `unescape()` but this also was not successful.

Comment: Which line threw the error?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are asking this here when it is a pure copy of another question on another site. If you are running into programming issues, then this *really* doesn't belong here.

Comment: Your code works *if you supply a base64-encoded valid Javascript* (try with: `var encoded = 'YWxlcnQoJ0hlbGxvIFdvcmxkJyk7Cg==';`). You very probably didn't, and Firefox tells you so. Check again your payload.

Comment: @schroeder the line containing eval throws this error